# Sort listView by passing it to my Sort class - c#

Tags: c#, class, sorting, listview, methods

I have a problem with passing a `listView` to a class and sorting it.

Let me explain what the idea of my program is:

In `Form1` I create a `listView` and I add items with subitems (name, date, number).

After that I created a `ColumnClick` event which sorts the items by the column the user clicked on.

My sort-algorithm works fine when it is in the same form as the `listView` is created in.

For the purpose of making my code better readable I decided to transfer my sort-algorithm to a separate C# file (lets call it `SortBy.cs`). The `ColumnClick` event then should call the sort-algorithm.

However, VisualStudio tells me that in `SortBy.cs` "The name 'ListViewNAME' does not exist in the current context'. Despite the fact that I have changed the the `listView` properties modifiers to public respectively.

How do I solve this problem and call my SortBy method properly?

I extracted the code from my project. For this purpose here it just contains three Items.

Edit code added:

Code Form1

```
namespace Project1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyList.View = View.Details;

        MyList.Columns.Add("Name", 170);
        MyList.Columns.Add("2.Sub", 170);
        MyList.Columns.Add("3.Sub", 170);

        ListViewItem Item1 = new ListViewItem("a");
        Item1.SubItems.Add("11");
        Item1.SubItems.Add("21");
        MyList.Items.Add(Item1);

        ListViewItem Item2 = new ListViewItem("b");
        Item2.SubItems.Add("12");
        Item2.SubItems.Add("22");
        MyList.Items.Add(Item2);

        ListViewItem Item3 = new ListViewItem("c");
        Item3.SubItems.Add("13");
        Item3.SubItems.Add("23");
        MyList.Items.Add(Item3);
    }

private void MyList_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Column == 0)
  {
    //normally: code for sorting by Name        
  }

  if (e.Column == 1)
  {
    //Code for sorting by Sub1         
  }

  if (e.Column == 2)
  {
    //Code for sorting by Sub2        
  }


}
```

Code SortBy:

```
namespace Project1
{
class SortBy
{
   public void Sorting()
   {
        int CounterOfList = MyList.Items.Count;
        //followed by sorting algorithm.
   }
}
}
```

To keep the post short I stripped-down the code. Like I said above my sorting does work if it is written down in  the `MyList_ColumnClick` event.

What I wanted to do is put my sorting-code into a class (I'm coming from c++; there it would be called a function) and call it when it is needed.

Therefore I somehow have to pass the `MyList` to `SortBy` to be able to work on it, or make it available for `SortBy`.

`Modifiers` properties of `MyList` are set to `public`. I also tested `internal` but it did not work.

In C++ I would call my function and I'm fine. But I dont know how to deal with this in C#.

Comment: You have to share some code. Otherwise it is a kind of miracle to find the right answer :) E.g. you could give the `ListView` as input parameter for the sort method. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your reference to what you would have done in C++ I'm assuming your difficulty is that in C# there are no "global" functions. That is, all functions must be class members. If you need such a global function you can make it static so that you don't need a class instance to invoke it. So, if you had public static void Sorting() you could call SortBy.Sorting(). Alternatively, you could pass your litst as a parameter of Sorting().

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you for your post. Calling `Sorting()` works but `MyList` is still unknown to the class `SortBy`. However my algorithm is dependig of having access to `MyList`. Like when I swap items with each other or adding / removing items.

Comment: I Think I got it! Thank you very much. I passed the ViewList from Form1 by parameter to a, I call it clone, and sort that clone. I think the next step is to return the now sorted clone to Form1 again. I'll try it.

Comment: It works I call it from Form1: `SortBy.Sorting(MyList)` . In the class `Sorting` I use `public static ... Sorting(ListView MyList)`  and then I can run my alorithm without a problem. Many thanks to you, Ian!

Comment: I removed a previous comment. Of course there's no need to explicity pass a reference type by reference as that is the default for reference types (as all class types are).